# Downgrading gcc and libc6 to fulfill CUDA 8 requirements on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 16.04, package-management, gcc, 16.10, downgrade

A few days ago I have switched from Fedora to Ubuntu to have better CUDA support,
but I've faced some problems with downgrading ***gcc*** and ***glibc/libc6*** packages to fulfill **CUDA 8** requirements.

But let's start at the very beginning. A couple days ago I've installed **Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety** with intention to install CUDA 8 drivers & toolkit.
I've compared my current versions with CUDA 8 requirements [docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/) :

CUDA 8 requirements are:

- Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0
- GCC 5.3.1
- GLIBC/LIBC6 2.23

My current setup is:

```
$ uname -vr
4.8.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 14:39:52 UTC 2016

$ dpkg -s gcc | grep Version
Version: 4:6.1.1-1ubuntu2

$ dpkg -s libc6 | grep Version
Version: 2.24-3ubuntu1
```

I thought that downgrading would be something as simple as typing one of the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc=5.3.1 
sudo apt-get install gcc=5.3
```

Unfortunatelly, those versions were not found for Yaketty.
I checked at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) (and by *apt-cache policy*) that the appropriate versions are only for Xenial and for Yakkety there's only **gcc-5 (5.4.1-2ubuntu2)** and **2.24-3ubuntu1** for libc6.

To sum up:

- I would like to downgrade gcc to 5.3.1 and glibc/libc6 to 2.23 and somehow manage these alternatives.
  I would prefer something like update-alternatives rather than using symbolic links directly (to take care of not only exectuables, but also all libraries).
- Could I downgrade preserving 100% stability by adding for a moment Xenial repository to list in: Software & Updates > Other Software ?
- Assuming that I would manage to downgrade gcc & libc6, could I install CUDA 8 on my current much higher kernel 4.8.0 (insetead of 4.4.0) without any loss in stability?
  (So far I've been using CUDA only on kernel versions exactly mentioned in installation guide.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S. I'm newbie to Ubuntu (only Fedora & RHEL so far), so this problem could be something very trivial.

Comment: I can't help but note that the CUDA Requirements indicate 16.04. Is there a specific reason you need 16.10? The reason I ask is 16.10 is only supported until July 2017 and 16.04 LTS is supported until April of 2021

Comment: Ok, I can reinstall to 16.04, but then I would like to install some other packages from Yakkety under Xenial, e.g. I would like to instal Yaketty's python-biopython 1.67 instead of Xenial 1.66. How to use different/higher repo 16.10 under 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had your specific set of requirements which required aspects of 16.04 as well as aspects of 16.10, I would take the easy way out and either dual boot both 16.04 and 16.10 or run 16.10 in a VM under Virtualbox running on a 16.04 host. I think this alternate approach would result in far more stable operations than attempting to mix packages designed for one with the other. (Granted this sometimes works, but it's not something I'd count on.)

To dual boot, simply tell the 16.04 installer to install alongside your existing 16.10 installation during the install process.

VirtualBox can be installed via the software center. [Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Documentation) is available, and if you get stuck There are many of us here eager to help with any *specific* difficulties

Comment: Thanks, I would simply reinstall to Xenial. All other required packages I'm able to install from sources and even biopython in the newest version 1.68 (newer than in Yakkety's 1.67).  By the way, I was asking about installing packages from other repos (newer or older distro) also for my curiosity. In Fedora I was able to install even from RHEL's, CentOS'  - it was not very clean solution , but working. I would simply get know how to do something similar under Ubuntu.

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek in that case I don't think you'll find that there is a great deal of difference between compiling from source and installing in Ubuntu as doing the same tasks under Fedora. You can even use [alien](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien)  to convert packages from rpm to deb. Not a very clean solution but I have had some success doing so on a few occasions.